# maven-clean-plugin not delete files

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I have the following pom.xml where I want to delete the `generated` directory after I put there some `*.java` files from `generate-sources` phase:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- This plugin generates java files in generated directory -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
            <executions>
                ...
            </executions>
        </plugin> 
        <!-- To clean the generated directory in service package -->           
        <plugin>
            <groupId>maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>/src/main/java/com/acme/Network/service/generated</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.log</exclude>
                        </excludes>  
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I want to have the entire package generated deleted with `maven clean` from m2e. But it just deletes ONLY the target dir and the generated dir stays untouched.

What am I doing  wrong?

Comment: What is a goal for you? `maven-clean-plugin` don't clean old or new java classes which generated `avro-maven-plugin`?

Comment: I want to clean the output of the `avro-maven-plugin` that is outside of the `target` directory. In `generated` directory to be specific.

Answer (score 11):

**First** - remove maven-clean-plugin from dependencies. It is plugin, not dependency.

**Second:** try

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/acme/Network/service/generated</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
```

Your path start with /src - it is global path from root / . For you the root is project ${basedir}

**Third:**
Generated sources should be added by convention to:

`${basedir}/target/generated-sources`
Then when you run "clean" - it will be removed also. And you can skip **second** step.

Use helper plugin to add other source package to the project (intellij and eclipse should see it):

```
     <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

**Update**
Override  [avro-maven-plugin](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html) in your pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${avro.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>schema</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I have removed the dependency and only plugin left. 
Adding `${basedir}` did not help still nothing happens with `generated`.
Why do I need this helper plugin for?

Comment: Your output for generated sources should be directory in target dir. Then when you call `maven clean` it remove target - with generated sources. Helper plugin is the information for maven - that it should compile also sources from other directory then src/main/java (here ${basedir}/target/generated-sources)

Comment: +1 It's sad that the Avro documentation lures people into generating the code in the `src/main/` folder which is very dangerous.

Comment: @ajozwik I am not sure if I understand. So without `maven helper` if I generate `mvn generate-sources` and then `maven compile` the `/target/generated-sources/` will not be taken under consideration and start compilation error?

Comment: Yes it will. Change your output to `<outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>`. And never start with / in maven configuration

Comment: @ajozwik Ok, but where to put this `<outputDirectory>` (avro plugin uses this as default) ? It was me who wanted to move it to `/src/main` but if you advise not to then i resign on this idea. So please just let me know assuming that I have my generated files in `target` how to configure the `helper plugin`?

Comment: Moreover in Eclipse u need to add this `generated-sources/avro` with rclick to build path too or else eclipse will not automatically import its classes for reference.

Comment: I always build generated sources in separate subproject - without any other sources. Then I added it as dependency. Project which generated only sources should be not inspected with pmd/findbugs/code coverage tools

Comment: @ajozwik Actually the without `maven helper` the `maven build` also works after `maven generate-sources`. So still WHY I NEED THIS PLUGIN?

Comment: Intellij Idea understands it - you do not need to add extra source directories. It makes it for you. If you just call on clean project (without sources generated) `mvn clean install` and all is built - then you do not need it.

Comment: @ajozwik You mentioned `I always build generated sources in separate subproject` How to do this?